# Implementing AutoCompletion using Solr

Tags: solr, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I would like to implement the autocompletion behaviour using Solr with my ADF application.I have configured my Solr server and able to get the values from Java code. I have tried implementing this for a text box using jQuery and Ajax but not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the built in autocomplete functionality in ADF with the af:autosuggestBehavior component?

https://pinboard.in/search/u:OracleADF?query=af%3AautoSuggestBehavior